# Click on ImageView without onClickListener

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, handler

is there any possibility to detect a click on an ImageView with a Handler (eg looking at it for 100 ms)? I mean is there a method of ImageView/View, which give me a boolean when someone has the finger on the ImageView?

Thank you!

EDIT: For all people in interest for an deep understanding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYoN-OvdZ3M&t=139s
That are 4 videos about the thematic. After this all my questions was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect whether the user has his finger on the imageview, you can use `setOnTouchListener`,

```
imageview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // This is a touch action.
        } 
    }
```

Other actions include ACTION_UP, ACTION_MOVE etc. Depending on what you want, you can trigger the click action by choosing the right touch event.

Comment: Thank you a lot! onTouchListener gave me all possibilitys for my project! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. You can use an onTouchListener if you want to know when a view is touched at all.

Comment: Thank you a lot! onTouchListener gave me all possibilitys for my project! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its called onClickListerner have you ever tried it? its amazing.

> imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>               @Override
>               public void onClick(View v) {
>                   }
>         });

or `setOnTouchListener()`

Comment: yes and i answered it. If you want to know how to click an image without a `onClickListener` the other way i told you is `setOnTouchListener` which will give you the event of the click. But if you want to handle a click action without a listener of any kind.. than its not possible.